# writing ls from scratch recursively

Tags: c, linux, directory

I am working on a simple project to implement "ls -R" from scratch.  Whenever I run what I have, my program just keeps searching the root directory over and over again.  What am I doing wrong?

```
void lsR(char dirName[]) {
/*
The recursive function call.  
*/

DIR *dir;
struct dirent *directory;
struct stat fileStat;
char type;
char **nameList[MAX_RECURSIVE_FILES];
struct passwd *user;
int count = 0;
int i = 0;


printf("\n");
printf("./%s :\n", dirName);
printf("\n");


if ((dir = opendir(dirName)) == NULL) {
    perror("opendir error:");
    return;
}

while ((directory = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {


    if (stat(directory->d_name, &fileStat) < 0) {
        perror("fstat error:");
        return;
    }
    if (fileStat.st_uid == 1) {
        continue;
    }

    user = getpwuid(fileStat.st_uid);
    printf("%s ", directory->d_name);

    fileType(&fileStat, &type);
    if ((type == 'd') && (count < MAX_RECURSIVE_FILES)) {

        nameList[count] = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
        strncpy(nameList[count++], directory->d_name, MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
    }

}
closedir(dir);
printf("\n");
for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
    printf("Calling lsR on: %s\n", nameList[i]);
    lsR(nameList[i]);
}
```

}

When it executes, I get the following output:

"./. :

., .., ... all other files in my current working directory ....

./. :

., .., ... all other files in my current working directory...

"

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the path relative to your program's current directory. Each `nameList` element will need to be `dirName` + `"/"` + `directory->d_name`.

If you started out calling `lsR` on the local directory, `./foo` and `foo` has directory named `bar` under it, then to open `bar` you need to open `./foo/bar` since your program is running from the directory represented by `.`.

Comment: What exactly is dirName to be?

Comment: @newalchemy `dirName` is what you passed into your function. In other words, you need to carry the whole relative path with any directory name you want to open.

Answer (score 1):

Among the list of files in the current directory you've noticed `.` and `..` The first one is a hardlink to the current directory and the second one to the parent directory. So when you recurse through your dir entries you will want to skip those two. Otherwise the first directory you will recurse into will be `.`, in other words the directory you've just gone through.

This is the reason of your program current behavior, but once you fix that you will run into the issue lurker mentioned in his answer.

Additional notes :

- Are you sure about the `char **nameList[MAX_RECURSIVE_FILES];` variable? Seems to me you want an array of `char *` not an array of `char **`.
- Are you aware you can use the `S_ISDIR` macro on the `st_mode` field of your `stat` struct, in order to check that the current file is not a directory instead of your custom function?

Comment: I actually use that macro in my custom function - I just wrote a custom function because I wanted a function that returned a letter.  I should use it for that though too.

As for skipping the . and .. directories, should I just start the loop at i=2 instead of i=0 ?

Comment: @newalchemy, I have never seen a directory without `.` and `..` in first position, but I can't find a source that says it is guaranteed. So skipping the first two entries would definitely work most of the time (all the time?), but if you want to be sure, make a comparison between `directory->d_name` and `.` and `..`.